# Values of zeta at odd positive integers and Borel's computations

Tags: analytic-number-theory, algebraic-k-theory, zeta-functions

Someone recently quoted to me this recent [article](http://www.ijpam.eu/contents/2014-91-1/11/) that claims to prove that $\zeta(2n+1) \notin (2\pi )^{2n+1} \mathbb{Q}$.

[Edit: published reference: Musha, Takaaki.
*Negation of the conjecture for odd zeta values*. Int. J. Pure Appl. Math. 91, No. 1, 103-111 (2014). Not referenced by MathSciNet, and referenced by zbMATH ([link](https://zbmath.org/1286.11008)).]

I always assumed this was well known. More precisely I thought this result followed from the fact that the regulator
$$
  K_{2n-1}(\mathbb{Z})\otimes \mathbb{Q} = \operatorname{Ext}^1_{MT(\mathbb{Z})}(\mathbb{Q}(0),\mathbb{Q}(n))    \longrightarrow \operatorname{Ext}^1_{MHS}(\mathbb{Q}(0),\mathbb{Q}(n)) = \mathbb{C}/(2\pi i)^n\mathbb{Q}
$$
is injective (this is usually quoted as a consequence of Borel's computations of K-groups "Stable real cohomology of arithmetic groups", "Cohomologie de $\operatorname{SL}_n$ et valeurs de fonctions zêta aux points entiers")

Am I mistaken?

Comment: Is there a typo in your noninclusion statement in the first line?  The zeta value is real, and what's on the right hand side is purely imaginary, so, yes, this is well-known, but probably not what you want to say.  

Comment: I checked the link -- Musha's statement does not have an $i$ in it: he claims to prove that $\zeta(2n+1) \not \in (2\pi)^{2n+1} \mathbb{Q}$.  I don't know much at all about algebraic K-theory so I may be poorly informed here, but it had always been my understanding that until the work of Apery, Rivoal etc., precisely nothing was known about the odd zeta values, and in particular the statement that Musha claims to prove was not known.  

Comment: Leading indicators on the paper:  uninformative abstract. "Interesting" search engine results for the author's name (antigravity propulsion, degrees not in math, 60 years old, etc). Breakthrough if correct, but was not publicized. Appears in an obscure journal.

Comment: @T: It has been discussed on this site before that we are generally not interested in non-expert opinions on whether a paper is correct, and, especially, opinions that are based on anything other than a careful reading of the paper.  I am particularly uncomfortable that you cite the author's age as a strike against him -- this seems downright discriminatory.  (Note that I cannot get free online access to the paper and therefore am certainly not claiming that it is correct.  I edited the question so as to make it sound like less of an endorsement of the paper's correctness.)  

Comment: Pete, how do you know T. isn't an expert? Anyway, following the links via Google as T. did led to Journal of Theoretics, a journal whose article titles suggest it is entirely devoted to the work of physics cranks, and in which Musha has multiple articles. The story of Heegner shows that amateurs can make breakthroughs, but just as well-known experts are often given benefit of the doubt when they make announcements without producing details, why shouldn't people who publish crank articles be doubted before seeing the details? 

Comment: @B: I don't know who T. is, and that's part of my point: it's hard to place much value in anonymous opinions.  But more to the point, even from an expert I don't want to see on a public forum opinions that are not based on the work itself.  Anyway, **of course** you're welcome to doubt the validity of someone's article that you haven't seen, for any reason.  [Was there anything in what I wrote that made you think that I have confidence in Musha's result?]  It is not always appropriate or wise to publicly express every opinion you have.

Comment: P.S.: The other thing is that the information that T. is providing is freely and easily available to everyone who is remotely interested.  (I googled the guy too.)  I just don't think we need any help in forming this kind of judgment.  

Comment: If anyone is interested in further discussion, I opened up a meta thread on this: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/659/sharing-negative-opinions-on-mo/#Item_1

Comment: @Pete, @BCnrd: I'm seeing this a few days late, and am not yet a user of meta.MO.  Age by itself is irrelevant but in conjunction with the other data does contribute to an initial assessment of the work, for reasons that have nothing to do with pejorative or discriminatory attitudes toward the elderly.  When someone has no known training or publication in the field (but does in antigravity "physics") claims a breakthrough as the first visible sign of math research, at age 60 it suggests that 30+ years of prior opportunity to engage with math were not taken. Which is another warning sign.

Comment: As a point of comparison, there was recently a 60-70 year old who solved a notorious open problem in graph theory, the Road Coloring Problem.  However, this man held a doctorate and a professorship in mathematics, and although he may not have solved any major problems before age 60 (or maybe he did, I don't know), he was known, as evidenced by publications, to have been working on the problem for years earlier with partial results, and on other mathematical problems. He did not suddenly take up engineering after no sign of interest in 30 yrs and claim to build an ultra-efficient automobile.

Comment: @AFK : the link seems to be broken.

Comment: I am surprised it took 6 years for the link to break.

Comment: @AFK It is an old post, but it was linked to in a reason MSE post, that's why I got here. Can you elaborate a bit on your cohomological reasoning in the post? Even if the below answer is correct and this injectivity does not prove the result, I would still be curious to understand better how it relates to zeta values in the first place

Answer (score 17):

It is not known (but conjectured) whether the numbers $\zeta(2n+1)/\pi^{2n+1}$ are irrational, $n=1,2,\dots$. It is not even known whether at least one of these numbers is irrational! In fact, the most general (folklore) conjecture states that $\pi$ and all odd zeta values are algebraically independent over $\mathbb Q$. There are natural links between this conjecture and the expected structure of the so-called multiple zeta values; the references I have in mind are papers by A. Goncharov and surveys/talks by M. Waldschmidt.